# Run a script in Google Sheets that generates formulas into cells when a specific cell is not empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a **script that generates 2 formulas in Col16 and Col17 when Col15 is edited**.
My formulas from the Google functions are:

- In Col16: =if(O12<>"";today();"")
- In Col17: =if(O12=""; ""; concatenate(text(P12;"YYYY-MM-DD");" - ";E12;" - "; O12))

I need this script to be run for 5 sheets called "Miriam", "Elisa", "Victor", "Hanane", "Sarah".

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Elisa-Miriam-Victor-Hanane-Sarah-Apoorva
  // target sheet of move to named Archive
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 2 or B
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  // When a client is mentioned in Col3, fill automatically Col23 or W by the PM name and generate the checkbox from data validation in Col2 or B   
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  var col23 = s.getRange(lastRow, 23).getValue();
    if (r.getRow() == lastRow && r.getColumn() == 3 && col23 == ""){
    s.getRange(lastRow, 23).setValue(s.getSheetName());
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build()
    s.getRange(lastRow,2).setDataValidation(rule);
  }

  // Fill automatically Columns P and Q when PO number is provided in Column O.
  //In P: generates the date of when the PO is mentioned; in Q: it generates the PO folder name
  var sh=event.range.getSheet();
  var namesA=["Miriam","Elisa","Hanane","Sarah","Apoorva","Victor"];
  if(namesA.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1 && e.range.columnStart==15) {
     event.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     event.range.offset(0,2).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=CONCATENATE(P%s,"-",E%s,P%s)',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart));
   }     

  // Archive a project with checked box from Archive Sheet
 if((s.getName() == "Miriam"||s.getName() == "Elisa"||s.getName() == "Hanane"||s.getName() == "Sarah"||s.getName() == "Apoorva"||s.getName() == "Victor")&& r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true) { // copy past every time a new PM-sheet is added
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } 


  // Unarchive a project from Archive sheet to respective owner
  else if(s.getName() == "Archive" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var nameColumn = 23;
    var name = s.getRange(row, nameColumn).getValue();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);   
}
}
```

I managed to generate in Col16 the date of when Col15 is edited. But **I don't understand why the script is not working for Col17 with the concatenate formula**.

Comment: What is not working mean?

Comment: Nothing is happening in Col17; I don't see the concatenate formula

Comment: What are you doing to debug your code?

Comment: Your offset is using CONCAT[0] and CONCAT[2] there is no CONCAT[2]

Comment: Sorry but I'm new in scripts... and I don't understand what you mean

Comment: CONCAT is an array `var CONCAT = [0,2]` it has two elements the first one is CONCAT[0] and the second one is CONCAT[1]  but your script  is using it this way `var concatformula = selectedCell.offset(CONCAT[0],CONCAT[2])` and there is no CONCAT[2].  If you still don't understand read this [JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Ok thank you for your help! I changed to CONCAT[1] and now it works (partly): I see the "--" but not the content in Col16-Col5-Col15; do you have any idea please?

Comment: Okay I think my formula works now.  Sorry for taking so long.  I don't use formulas much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var namesA=["Miriam","Elisa","Hanane","Sarah","Apoorva","Victor"];
  if(namesA.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1 && e.range.columnStart==15) {
     e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     e.range.offset(0,2).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=CONCATENATE(P%s,"-",E%s,P%s)',e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart,e.range.rowStart));
   }     
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help again! Do I need to define Utilities? I still don't manage to generate the concatenate in the cell :crying:

Comment: Utilities is part of the core services.

Comment: Share a copy of your current code in your question.

Comment: Well, you certainly have a lot going on in your onEdit().  I try to keep them simple because the have to finish in  30 seconds. Any way the onEdit in my example seems to work okay so may be it has something to do with the other sections.  Good luck finding it.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the utilities. I just copy pasted your script into a new script file (so there is no other information on it) and the color of "utilities" is unchanged. So the script works for the date generation but I still don't manage to have the concatenation. Again, thank you for your help and have a good week-end

Comment: I just tested it on my account and it puts stuff into columns 16 and 17

Comment: I've #ERROR. That's fine, I'll figure it out. Thank you you have helped me a lot already.

Comment: Hello @jdsr, since the `#ERROR` in your Spreadsheet is related to the formula being parsed wrongly, can you check if you don't have any extra/missing brackets or quotation marks?

Comment: Hello ale13, thank you for your comment. I started everything from the beginning on a new spreadsheet, with no script, and the script from @Cooper is working. I'm sorry for the inconvenience! I have the concatenation as I wanted :) Thank you to both of you!